# Unrecognized extra characters in file parsed with php

Tags: php, file, unicode, csv

I've got a csv file I'm parsing with PHP. (Actually, it's tab-separated.) In a text editor, the file looks like this:

```
Object Id   Page/Master Id  Page/Master Name ...
```

Using this code:

```
$f = file_get_contents($filepath);
echo $f;
```

I get this in the browser:

```
��O�b�j�e�c�t� �I�d� �P�a�g�e�/�M�a�s�t�e�r� �I�d� �P�a�g�e�/�M�a�s�t�e�r� �N�a�m�e� ...
```

with all those question mark characters. If I use strlen() to count the number of chars, it reports twice as many as it should. I suspect it has something to do with unicode, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may be wrong, but this smells like an UTF-16 encoded file. Can you try

```
$f = iconv("utf-16", "utf-8", $f);
```

?

Comment: The character spacing almost certainly indicates it is a unicode file. utf-16 is a very likely guess too.

Comment: In particular, it is UTF-16LE (little-endian) encoding, the UTF-16 variant Windows misleadingly describes as just “Unicode”. The two bytes at the start are a Byte Order Mark that will allow `utf-16`-with-unspecified-endianness to work by automatically detecting the little-endianness.